# Textarea screenshot using Html2Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, screenshot, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas library to take screenshots. This is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sodofkcs/42/).

It takes a sreenshot of the textarea when click the `to image` button.

Currently it is ignoring the scroller text and only taking the screenshot which is visible on the textarea. I want to take the screenshot of whole textarea text.

```
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
    width: 320,
    height: 220
  });
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you take the screenshot, set the textarea height to include everything. Then reset the height after ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/sodofkcs/44/)):

```
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById("target");
  textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";
  html2canvas(textarea, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      textarea.style.height = "";
    },
    width: 320,
    height: textarea.offsetHeight
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks currently the screen shot shows everything in the single line,http://jsfiddle.net/sodofkcs/46/ If you check this example it will screen shot the multi line input in a single line @Mottie